# Retina @2x high-resolution graphics wrongly used on standard display

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

It appears that some images are incorrectly drawn, using their high-resolution equivalent, while others are fine. why is that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSImage seems to forcefully choose @2x high-res images when drawn images are **stretched**

To avoid this, you can either choose to use [NSDrawThreePartImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_40) or [NSDrawNinePartImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_39)

These functions will avoid stretching by tiling-up patterns.

And if you really can’t use the above but want to avoid the 2x representation being used:

```
[NSImage setMatchesOnlyOnBestFittingAxis:YES]
```